# groupby does not apply effectively

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Following is the ranking dataframe i am working on:

```
               Q6     Q17
1      Consultant     NaN
2           Other     NaN
3  Data Scientist    Java
4    Not employed  Python
5    Data Analyst     SQL
```

I want to:

1. count how many times each programming language occurs for 'Data Scientists' and record the frequency in a column 'counts'
2. sort the count in descending order
3. reset index and rename Q17 as Language

The following code does not *group* each Language.

```
ranking_data = ranking_data[ranking_data.Q6 == 'Data Scientist']
ranking_data_summary = ranking_data.copy().rename(columns = {'Q17':'Language'})
ranking_data_summary['counts'] = ranking_data_summary.groupby('Language') 
['Language'].transform('count')
ranking_data_summary.sort_values('counts',ascending = False, inplace = True)
ranking_data_summary.reset_index(inplace = True)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Making it more complicated than it needs to be. `pd.crosstab(df.Q6, df.Q17)`

Comment: But you could do `df.query('Q6 == "Data Scientist"').Q17.value_counts()`

Comment: This should work fine: `ranking_data[ranking_data["Q6"] == "Data Scientist"].groupby("G17").count()`

Comment: @piRSquared I needed to return a dataframe itself.. thanks anyway!